# How to bring changes from an old commit to your present commit without loosing your current progress

Tags: git

I stumbled across a problem when was working in a branch (let's call it) `y`.

Here's a roadmap of my work in `y`:

```
... --> important-commit --> commit2 --> commit3
```

It turned out that changes in `important-commit` were erased with `commit2`. I want my `commit3` to have all the data from the `important-commit`.

My problem is that I don't know how to bring changes from `important-commit` and also save work done in `commit3`

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `git cherry-pick`.  Functionally, cherry-picking a commit means to *copy* the commit, by turning the commit's snapshot into a change-set and applying that change-set to the current commit to yield a new commit.

That is, what `git cherry-pick $hash` does is, in essence:

```
git diff $hash^1 $hash > /tmp/patch   # see what changed in $hash vs its parent
git apply /tmp/patch                  # and then if this works, commit
```

(though in fact it will use the full power of Git's merge machinery to deal with changes introduced *since* commit `$hash`: the above is merely meant as an aid to understanding the process).

Note that `git revert`, which [Tim Biegeleisen suggested using on the subsequent commit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48137097/1256452), is very similar to `git cherry-pick`.  The key difference is that `git revert` *reverses the diff*: if the diff says "add new line 37 to `README.txt`", `git revert` will *remove* that line from `README.txt` rather than trying to add it again.  If the diff says "change `orange` to `purple`", cherry-pick will try to change orange to purple but revert will try to change purple back to orange.

In other words, `git revert` really means *re-do this by backing it out* wile `git cherry-pick` means *re-do this by re-doing it*.  Both are implemented internally using the same code (which Git calls the *sequencer;* recent versions of Git use the sequencer to implement interactive rebase as well).

Answer (score 0):

If you can tolerate completely undoing commit #2, then `git revert` is one option here:

```
git checkout y
git revert <SHA-1 of commit #2>
```

This will add a new commit to the HEAD of your `y` branch which will functionally undo everything which commit #2 did, including erasing the important changes from the previous commit.

Comment: And if you can't, you can start with `git revert -n`; or you can instead use `git cherry-pick` (with or without `-n`) using anything that identifies the important commit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git checkout important-commit file1 file2 file3` to specify **only** the files that you need.